# Laravel search by date, title with pagination 5.7

Tags: laravel, eloquent

> I have few problem. Firstly need to show index with $projects with pagination if user didn't search anything. Second when i search something pagination is not working(blank).

**View**

```
{!! Form::open(['method'=>'get']) !!}
     <input class="form-control" name="date" value="{{ request('date') }}" type="date"/> 
     <input class="form-control" name="search" value="{{ request('search') }}" type="text"/>
<div class="input-group-btn">
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Хайх</button>
</div>
{!! Form::close() !!}

<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
   ---------------
</table>

{{ $projects->links() }}
```

**Controller**

```
 $search = $request->get('search');
 $date = $request->get('date');
 $projects = Project::where('title','like','%'.$search.'%')
                ->whereDate('created_at', $date)
                ->orderBy("created_at",'desc')
                ->paginate(10)
                ->withPath('?search=' . $search);
 return view('projects.index', compact('projects'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> just minor change you need.

**View**

```
{!! Form::open(['method'=>'get']) !!}
     <input class="form-control" name="date" value="{{ request('date') }}" type="date"/> 
     <input class="form-control" name="search" value="{{ request('search') }}" type="text"/>
<div class="input-group-btn">
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Хайх</button>
</div>
{!! Form::close() !!}

<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
   ---------------
</table>

{{ $projects->appends(request()->query() }}
```

**Controller**

```
 $search = $request->get('search');
 $date = $request->get('date');
 $projects = Project::where('title','like','%'.$search.'%')
                ->whereDate('created_at', $date)
                ->orderBy("created_at",'desc')
                ->paginate(10);
 return view('projects.index', compact('projects'));
```